# Сделать запрос к апи сайта, получить ответ и распарсить

Tags: api, django-rest-framework

СДЕЛАТЬ ЗАПРОС К API САЙТА, ПОЛУЧИТЬ ОТВЕТ И РАСПАРСИТЬ.

Доброго времени суток. Я новичок в Django Rest Framework. Я хочу попробывать написать программу, которая будет собирать отзывы о "Вкусно и точка" в Уфе. Получается, что нужно будет реализовать получение отзывов, например, с сайтов 2gis и Flamp. Выходные данные. Раз в день придётся ещё опросить эти сайты на предмет новых отзывов:

- Автор
- Дата/время
- рейтинг
- текст отзыва

Дополнительно по возможности думаю ещё реализовать отправку новых отзывов на телеграмм и хранить данные в БД.

Задание, кажется, простым для тех, кто в этом разбирается, но я никак подойти к решению не могу, рецепты из интернета приводят мой vsc к ошибкам.

Comment: а к чему тут drf?

Comment: Просто хотел уточнить, что единственный мой опыт: это теория из курсов Django Rest Framework, Django API, сериализаторы и вьюсеты. Но у меня всё равно возникает сложность в выполнении подобных задач. Хотелось бы, чтобы опытные подсказали, помогли. Тогда пойму на практике как правильно сделать запрос к апи сайта, получить ответ и распарсить.

Comment: ну для этих задач вам нужно 2 библиотеки `requests` и `bs4`. Ну и потом еще какая-нибудь библиотека для работы с бд.